# Loop through each line in a text file to extract a unique list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to extract a unique list of datanames from a text file but I can't seem to do it as I have no knowledge of regex.

If we have the example:

```
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:55] The user user01 | account01 | namename1 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:57] The user user two | account_two | name2 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:59] The user user_three | account_ | name3 here3 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:31:41] The user user01 | account01 | namename1 has been granted access.
```

I want it to basically find the account information between the two pipes `|` and strip out the pipes and whitespace so it would output a list into a text file with just the following, after it has gone through and removed any duplicates so it is strictly a pure list

```
account01
account_two
account_
```

One check it must do is make sure it only gets the account information if the line contains the phrase `has been granted access.` because the data could look like:

```
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:55] The user user01 | account01 | namename1 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:57] The user user two | account_two | name2 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:59] Details Granted | user two | access number 01239
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:30:59] The user user_three | account_ | name3 here3 has been granted access.
[Friday 17/10/2014 @ 07:31:41] The user user01 | account01 | namename1 has been granted access.
```

I wouldn't want it to get the account information `user two` from line 3 of that example.

Could anyone help with some examples bits of code? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely overlooked split... but here is a fully working version based on using split:

Splits by `|` and chooses the second part of the split, it then strips out all whitespace, it then produces an accountlist by checking if the account isn't in the list this way it removes duplicates

Lastly but not least it then outputs all of the accounts to to output.txt

```
accountlist = []
with open('mydatafile.txt', 'r') as infile: 
    for line in infile:
        if "has been granted access." in line:
            if line.strip().split('|')[1].strip(" ") not in accountlist:
                accountlist.append(line.strip().split('|')[1].strip(" "))
    print accountlist

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for account in accountlist:
            outfile.write("%s\n" % account)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> granted_accounts = [line.split('|')[1].strip() for line in open('file.txt') if 'has been granted access' in line]
>>> print(granted_accounts)
['account01', 'account_two', 'account_', 'account01']
```

If you want to be able to execute it on the command line, just put the two lines with a shebang in a .py file like so (search.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
granted_accounts = [line.split('|')[1].strip() for line in open('file.txt') if 'has been granted access' in line]
print(granted_accounts)
```

And run like so:

```
$ python search.py
```

or:

```
$ chmod +x search.py
$ ./search.py
```

If you have a lot of accounts, you may want to print each account only once and on a separate line:

```
>>> granted_accounts = [line.split('|')[1].strip() for line in open('file.txt') if 'has been granted access' in line]
>>> print('\n'.join(sorted(set(granted_accounts))))
account01
account_
account_two
```

Comment: why we need to change thed script as executable?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: if you had read the next line you see that it's possible to execute without having to manually pick interpretor. If you're running MinGW under Windows you won't need this.

Comment: The execute on the command line stuff is not pertinent, and anyway, the Python interpreter binary will not always be in `/bin` as you assume, indeed it is more commonly found in `/usr/bin`. Better yet, use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the shebang to use $PATH to locate a suitable Python binary.

Comment: AvinashRaj: true, fixed (too much cut'n'paste today). @mhawke: true, fixed. I'm curious: do you know how dists decide on where stuff go in the directory tree?

Comment: For big files, i suggest to generator expressions `(line.split('|')[1].strip() for line in open('file.txt') if 'has been granted access' in line)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_granted_accounts(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
      return set(
               s.split('|')[1].strip() 
               for s in f.readlines() 
               if "has been granted access" in s)
```

This piece of code will work with some caveat:

- pipes cannot occur in the first or second field (quoted, escaped)
- "has been granted access" should appear only in the expected field (not as account name, for instance)

Comment: "removed any duplicates" is missing. Should call set()

Comment: Right, I changed the code to comply with @DavidosKrausos observation